# How to list all the fees charged by Stripe via API for accounting purpose?

Tags: stripe-payments

Unfortunately Stripe does not issue its own invoices for US accounts as per the following documentation:

https://support.stripe.com/questions/download-vat-or-gst-invoices-for-stripe-fees

Therefore it is harder to bulk reconcile processing fees and payouts in the US than in the EU.

Some accountants suggest to use the information summed up under Balances > Payouts > Payout (item)

[image: screenshot]

It would indeed be convenient to collect the fees via the payout object however the API doesn't seem to include processing fees in:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts

Here are some of the line items that our monthly Tax invoice contains in the EU:

- Stripe Processing Fees
- Refunded Fees
- Dispute Fees
- Dispute Fees Refunded
- Chargeback Protection Stripe Fees
- Radar Stripe Fees...

How to list all the fees charged by Stripe via API for accounting purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section about [balance transactions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions) contains all the relevant information. Furthermore all balance types are listed [here](https://stripe.com/docs/reports/balance-transaction-types#balance_related).

**Code example in php**

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'sk_................'
);

    try{
        
        $transactions = $stripe->balanceTransactions->all(array(
        
            'limit'     => 100,
            //'type'    => 'stripe_fee',
        ));
    }
    catch(Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
      
        //echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**Object Sample**

```
{
  "id": "txn_1AznDOBVdKJBvdqlJZmzAT6P",
  "object": "balance_transaction",
  "amount": 406,
  "available_on": 1505433600,
  "created": 1504879934,
  "currency": "eur",
  "description": null,
  "exchange_rate": null,
  "fee": 37,
  "fee_details": [
    {
      "amount": 37,
      "application": null,
      "currency": "eur",
      "description": "Stripe processing fees",
      "type": "stripe_fee"
    }
  ],
  "net": 369,
  "reporting_category": "charge",
  "source": "ch_1AznDOBVdKJBvdqlKp5lunlU",
  "status": "available",
  "type": "charge"
}
```

**Note**

Webhooks can be setup for all the relevant datapoints in order to fetch balance information.

If the type is "stripe_fee" get the amount directly from the field "amount" otherwise from "fee" or "fee_details"

If connected accounts are used the process also requires to use the connected "account_ids" for fetching data.

**References**

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions
- https://stripe.com/docs/reports/balance-transaction-types#balance_related
- https://www.reddit.com/r/stripe/comments/qcooyu/how_to_list_the_stripe_processing_fees_via_api/

Comment: Additionally for manual extraction, instead of using CSVs,  you can get the monthly fees in one line via: Reports > Financial reports > Balance (tab) then select the month and read the "Less fees" line or export by clicking "print"